# Saving an array globally

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**What I'm trying to achieve**

I have a spreadsheet with 2 sheets `A` & `B`.

- `A` has 2 columns - Name, Amount (Master List)
- `B` has 4 columns - Name, Amount, X, Y (Transaction List)

*Name* column of `Sheet B` references *Name* column of `Sheet A` for data. Whenever a name is selected, I want to populate Amount column in `B` with Amount in column of `sheet A` as a placeholder which users can override. For this, I plan to load the `Sheet A` data in an array (available Globally) so that in `onEdit(e)` I can refer that array instead of accessing `Sheet B`.

But the options I could find - `CacheService` and `PropertyService` - save only string values. But I want to have:

```js
var myGlobalArray = [];

function on init(){
    //iterate and fill the array such that it has following output
    //myGlobalArray[Name1] = 1
    //myGlobalArray[Name2] = 2
    //myGlobalArray[Name3] = 3
}

function onEdit(e){ 
  //if selected value is name1, populate myGolbalArray[Name1] value in Amount
}
```

**Question**
Where & how to define myGlobalArray?

I tried to use cache service with `JSON.Stringify` and `JSON.parse` but the array is empty in `onEdit`.

Comment: Show your stringify code. Its not there

Comment: Seems that I found the issue. I'm using associative arrays and JSON.stringify saves them as [] instead of full array. But if I use [{key:value}] I'll need to do iterations to find things which will waste the whole activity of performance gain

Comment: Json.stringify perfectly saves any object. Your issue cant be that.

Comment: @Spencer picked up the missing thread - you keep saying "Array", when you mean "associative array", which is actually an object with named properties. (You should have showed more code, to make your question clearer. That's why SO asks for the "minimal code required to replicate the problem".)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each call to your script creates a new instance of your script with its own unique globals. Every time you call a script you will actually find a global "this" for that specific instance.  You are correct to look at PropertyService as a persistent way to save data.

Right off I See that your globalArray is not set up right:

```
var myGlobalArray = [];
```

needs to be

```
 var myGlobalArray = {};
 myGlobalArray['name1'] = 1
 myGlobalArray['name2'] = 2
 myGlobalArray['name3'] = 3

 //myGlobalArray = {name3=3.0, name1=1.0, name2=2.0}
 var stringArray =  JSON.stringify(myGlobalArray)
 //{"name1":1,"name2":2,"name3":3};
```

Now that can be saved to and read from the property store.

```
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("NameArray", stringArray);
stringArray = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("NameArray");
myGlobalArray = JSON.parse(stringArray);
Logger.log(myGlobalArray['name1']) // returns 1
```

Comment: "Globals in Apps Script do not behave like client side Javascript." Actually, this is _exactly_ like client side Javascript, since globals in browser clients don't survive between sessions, but need to be cached somewhere (e.g. in a cookie). Each invocation of `onEdit()` is in effect a new session, akin to a new tab in the browser. But Kudos for pointing out the associative array use!

Comment: You are correct.  I will change that,  but a common misconception is that the "tab stays open" after the script finishes running.  You did a good explanation on your post.

Comment: np! It's a topic that comes up frequently, and is very confusing to the uninitiated.

Comment: What is the Array I wish to store is multi-dimensional ? How do we use PropertyService in this case to store data ?

Answer (score 4):

It's true that CacheService and PropertyService save only string values, but you can store any scalar data by using the [`JSON` utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#working_with_json) [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```js
// Save an array in cache service
CacheService.getPublicCache()
            .put("myGlobalArray", JSON.stringify(myGlobalArray));

// Retrieve an array from property service
var myGlobalArray = JSON.parse( CacheService.getPublicCache()
                                                 .get("myGlobalArray") );

// Save an array in property service
PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()
                 .setProperty("myGlobalArray", JSON.stringify(myGlobalArray));

// Retrieve an array from property service
var myGlobalArray = JSON.parse( PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()
                                                 .getProperty("myGlobalArray") );
```

When a variable is called "Global", we are referring to its *scope*, saying that it is available to all code within the same module. (You can read more about scope in [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript))

But since you're looking at CacheService and PropertyService, you already know that scope is only part of the problem. Each time that `onEdit()` is invoked, it will be running in a new execution instance on one of Google's servers. A value that had been in a global variable in a previous instance will not be available to this new instance. Therefore, we need to populate our "global variable" in each new invocation of our script.

An elegant way to reference global variables is as names properties of the special [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) object. For example, every function in our script can refer to `this.myGlobalArray`.<sup>1</sup>

You can adapt the `getRssFeed()` example from the [Class Cache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache) documentation into `get_myGlobalArray()`, say. Then your `onEdit()` trigger needs only to call that first to make sure that `this.myGlobalArray` contains the relevant array data.

```js
function onEdit(e){ 
  get_myGlobalArray();

  //if selected value is name1, populate myGlobalArray[Name1] value in Amount
  ...
  sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(),2).setValue(myGlobalArray[e.value]);
}

/**
 * Ensure the global variable "myGlobalArray" is defined and contains the
 * values of column A in SheetA as an array.
 */
function get_myGlobalArray() {
  if (typeof this.myGlobalArray == 'undefined') {
    // Global variable doesn't exist, so need to populate it
    // First, check for cached value
    var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();
    var cached = cache.get("myGlobalArray");
    if (cached) {
      // We have a cached value, so parse it and store in global
      this.myGlobalArray = JSON.parse(cached);
    }
    else {
      // No value in the cache, so load it from spreadsheet
      var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet A").getDataRange().getValues();
      this.myGlobalArray = {};
      for (var row=0; row<data.length; row++) {
        this.myGlobalArray[data[row][0]] = data[row][6];
      }

      // Stringify and store the global into the cache
      cache.put("myGlobalArray", JSON.stringify(this.myGlobalArray));
    }
  }
}
```

#### Edit: Associative Array

In the comment within `onEdit()`, it's indicated:

```js
//if selected value is name1, populate myGolbalArray[Name1] value in Amount
```

This implies that `myGlobalArray` is an *associative array*, where the index is a non-integer value. This requirement is now reflected in the way that `this.myGlobalArray` gets populated when read from the spreadsheet.

```js
for (var row=0; row<data.length; row++) {
  this.myGlobalArray[data[row][0]] = data[row][6];
  //                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  //  Name ---------------/           /
  //  Amount ------------------------/
}
```

Much has been written about the different flavours of Javascript arrays, for instance [Javascript Associative Arrays Demystified](http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/).

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, only functions with global scope would understand `this` to mean "global to the script". Functions that are contained inside objects would interpret `this` to mean their host object only. But that's a story for another day.